# Battery fast discharging

Tags: dc-motor, discharge, mobile-robot

It is my first question on this forum. I have a problem with my arduino project. I am working on a mobile robot. I use L298P Motor Shield for controlling the two 5v gearbox motors. The power supply is from 3 x 3.7V 12000 mah batteries.The problem is that after few seconds of use the motor stops because of battery discharge.The robot is around 3 kg weight. Should I buy bigger motors?

Comment: We need to know what current the motor draws at full load. Current at 80% and when just stalled will also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a 3S pack at 12000mAh means that the batteries should be able to supply 12A for an hour,

As the drivers are only rated for 4A per output, you would then expect it to run for about 1.5 Hours under full load - what ever the rest of the system is drawing for your use case

I fail to see why you would think larger motors would resolve this

If the battery pack voltage is really falling below about 7V (minimum rated voltage for the driver chips), then you have a bad connection or a really poor battery pack,

Another thing that might be going wrong is the large current spike when you start or stop the motor could be coupling a large amount of noise into the supply of what is controlling the drivers (the arduino), I would recommend making sure the motor power wiring is separate from the arduino supply wiring

Comment: I thought bigger motors would solve my problem because robot starts moving only at 80% duty cycle. I needed slower speed so I decreased the duty cycle. This probably overloaded the motors and discharged the battery. In my project I need torque rather than speed.

Answer (score 0):

"bigger motors" is a random change. Changing things at random is a poor way to debug a system.

Analyse what is happening and fix what isn't working.

For example, motors are most efficient at speeds close to their unloaded speed. Measure motor speed, voltage, current with the wheels (track, legs, fins, whatever) in the air, and measure again with them driving the robot. If they are much slower and consuming more current, gear the motors down until they run at least 75% of the unloaded speed.

If the end result is too slow, compute the power you need and re-design with a motor that exceeds that power (with the drive current and gearing for that new motor).